# Ubuntu (dual boot) can see mobile hotspot but not main network

Tags: wireless

I can only see other networks including my phone's hotspot but not my main wifi network.

Everything worked fine up until randomly the connection would be lost at boot and only after restarting the router a couple times (sometimes once, sometimes more) would the network appear and I could connect to it.

my network driver is BCM4352 802.11ac from the bcmwl-kernel-source package.

I tried a lot of the advice online but nothing worked.

Comment: Change the router settings to use channel 1-11

Comment: my router is set to channel 13, I am using vodafone though and I don't think I can change it, will look into it !

Comment: This worked !! God this was a pain, if anyone is going through the same problem, to change the channel with vodafone, you have to install the mobile app, and change the setting under wifi/advanced settings. Thanks you ! now out of curiosity, why do channels outside of 1-11 not get picked up by the card on linux only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered by Jeremy31 in the comment under the question.
The drivers were fine, it was the channel (set to 13) needing to be set in the 1-11 range. Since I was using a vodafone router I had to change that setting through the mobile app, for some reason you cannot do it on the web interface.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install firmware-b43-installer. Please follow this step by step: Downloads can be done from other computer with Internet too.

1. Remove this kernel module (if installed) `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`
2. Download these 2 files:

   http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_019-4_amd64.deb
   http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-6.30.163.46.tar.bz2
3. Copy them to your Ubuntu Home folder
4. Go to your Home folder and Run in terminal `sudo dpkg -i b43-fwcutter_019-4_amd64.deb`
5. Extract with `tar xfvj broadcom-wl-6.30.163.46.tar.bz2`
6. Then `sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-6.30.163.46.wl_apsta.o`
7. Run `sudo modprobe b43`
8. Reboot
9. Your WiFi shall be available by now.
10. Install `broadcom-sta-dkms`, `broadcom-sta-common` & `broadcom-sta-source` from the Ubuntu repo (via terminal or via synaptic package manager)
11. Reboot

Below is the image of my present .bash_history, you may see the commands I used there. Ignore the line Ubuntu_Broadcom_wifi_Fix, as that's the name of the folder I saved the downloaded files.

[image]

Done

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! So the names of the files are slightly different, they're called: "b43-fwcutter_015-9_amd64.deb" and "broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2" and at step 6. i am getting an error: "maks@maks-linux:/lib/firmware$ sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-6.30.163.46.wl_apsta.o
Cannot open input file broadcom-wl-6.30.163.46.wl_apsta.o
"

Comment: I also tried: "maks@maks-linux:~$ sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-5.100.138
Sorry, the input file is either wrong or not supported by b43-fwcutter.
This file has an unknown MD5sum d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.
"

Comment: If you click the links, they give exactly those files for downloads, I just tested. I have been doing it for my every Ubuntu installation, since 18.04. Okay, wait, I got it, let me change the file names. Done now.

Comment: After following the instructions i get the "No Wi-Fi" Adepter Found message in my Wi-fi tab

Comment: You have to reboot, then you'll see the wifi adapter there, else repeat the process

Comment: I did follow the steps, it just didn't work, repeating won't help

Comment: Can you connect an ethernet or mobile hotspot? Then you can install the above modules from the repo.

Comment: Please check the updated response